# How can is solve Python 3.6 itertools error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations, python-itertools, combinatorics

So, I have this very-very basic code:

```py
t = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ... 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89,90]
c = list(itertools.combinations(t, 5))
print(c)
```

When I run this it takes approximately 15 seconds and then it gives the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/<path>/main.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(c)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

But, when I run this code:

```py
t = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
c = list(itertools.combinations(t, 5))
print(c)
```

It gives me no error instead my desired output which is:

```py
[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (1, 2, 3, 4, 6), (1, 2, 3, 4, 7), ... (10, 7, 8, 9, 10), (6, 7, 8, 9, 10)]
```

Why doesn't it works with more numbers in list `t`?

I don't insist on `itertools` so you can show me another example of doing this. It just has to give every combination without repetition.

Comment: Why do you need to put all the combinations into a list?

Comment: A list with ~40m tuples may be too much for your system/console to handle…?

Comment: The size of the list `c` is `43,949,268` tuples of `5` elements. I am guessing your OS has a little issue with printing this (understandably...)

Comment: Try printing each tuple separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
t = range(1, 91)
c = itertools.combinations(t, 5)

for i in c:
    print(i)
```

It ran in my computer about 10 minutes and finiseshes correctly with the last combination `(86, 87, 88, 89, 90)`.

The difference is that I didn't create a list, so `c` is a *generator*, i. e. it generates only 1 combination at a time, which I immediately printed.